# select from tbl where tbl.field is min

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have select

```
SELECT e.*, b.f1, b.fee FROM eq e JOIN br b ON e.country = b.country
WHERE e.name= 'some' AND b.fee = 1
```

I need rewrite select an replace `AND b.fee = 1` to `AND b.fee = min fee from b`

I can not....I can `AND b.fee = (SELECT MIN(fee)FROM br)`  But it bad solution

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only one row, then just use `limit`:

```
SELECT e.*, b.f1, b.fee
FROM eq e JOIN
     br b
     ON e.country = b.country
WHERE e.name = 'some'
ORDER BY b.fee
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want all rows with the minimum free, then here is one method:

```
SELECT e.*, b.f1, b.fee
FROM eq e JOIN
     (SELECT b.*, MIN(fee) OVER () as minfee
      FROM br b
     ) b
     ON e.country = b.country
WHERE e.name = 'some' AND b.fee = minfee;
```

Comment: ORDER BY b.fee
LIMIT 1;  - It's not a heavy operation if there are a lot of records?

Comment: @user5620472 . . . If you don't have an index on `fee`, it is roughly as expensive as just about any other way of getting the minimum.  If you have an index, the order by might or might not be able to take advantage of it.